# Django: read an uploaded file and add content to a textarea field in the model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a model that has a filefiled to upload docx files(e.g cv). I would like to read the contents of this file and add it to a textarea field (e.g experience), such that the contents are saved to the database. Need help on how to go about this. I am aware of REQUEST.FILES but don't know how to piece it together

Answer (score 0):

You can use the docxtemplater,(link:https://github.com/open-xml-templating/docxtemplater) to extract the data.

The details can be found in the this link:[get docx file contents using javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28440170/get-docx-file-contents-using-javascript-jquery)

You can use jquery/javascript to set the value of the textarea to extracted data.

Comment: But how does this work with Django because it contents of the file needs to be saved when copied into the textarea

Comment: Jquery can extract data at frontend and change the value of textarea. You can send the data in textarea to backend and save it in db once you click the submit button.